# US East based Azure SQL Database rates

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ratecard-api

I am unable to find the unit rate for an Azure Standard S3 SQL database in the US East region. I don't find this information in the Azure Rate Card JSON file.
Expected Meter Category - Data Services
Expected Meter Sub Category - SQL Database
Expected  Region - US East

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This should be a question to MS Support team. Not for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. This should be asked to the Microsoft support staff or in Microsoft's Support Forums.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Standard S3 on East US is $0.2017/hr

Please visit [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) URL, select the region, then make a click “Single Database”.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: Thanks Alberto. I do see the price on the portal UI.  I am however not able to find a corresponding construct in the Azure Rate Card JSON file.